# Estimating parameters in multivariate classification resulting zero determinant sample covariance matrix

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification, estimation, covariance

Newbie here typesetting my question, so excuse me if this don't work.

I am trying to give a ***bayesian classifier*** for a multivariate classification problem where input is assumed to have ***multivariate normal distribution***. I choose to use a discriminant function defined as $\log (likelihood \times prior)$.

However, from the distribution,

$f(x \mid\mu,\Sigma) = (2\pi)^{-N \times d/2}\det(\Sigma)^{-N/2}exp[(-1/2)(x-\mu)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)]$

i encounter a term $-\log(det(S_i))$, where $S_i$ is my sample covariance matrix for a specific class i. Since my input actually represents a square image data, my $S_i$ discovers quite some correlation and resulting in $det(S_i)$ being zero. Then my discriminant function all turn $\infty$, which is disastrous for me.

I know there must be a lot of things go wrong here, anyone willling to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $\log|S_i|$ by $\sum_{j=1}^{J} \log\lambda_j$ where $\lambda_1>\ldots>\lambda_p$ are the $p>J$ eigenvector of $S_i$ in decreasing order ($S_i$ is a $p$ by $p$ square matrix) and $\lambda_{J+1}$ is the first eigenvalue smaller than a numerical 0 threshold (say 1e-9).

As for the second term (e.g. --$(x-\mu)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$--), replace $S_i$ by

$$\pmb P_{J}^{}\pmb D_J\pmb P_J'$$

where

$$\pmb D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{p})$$

and

$$S_i=\pmb P^{}\pmb D\pmb P'$$

is the eigenvector decomposition of $S_i$ (ordered in decreasing order of the $\lambda_j$'s) and $\pmb P_{J}$ is the matrix formed 
of the first $J$ columns of $\pmb P$ and $\pmb D_J$ is the diagonal matrix formed
 of the first $J$ rows and columns of $\pmb D$.

Note that for that $i$-th class, your estimates will no longer be affine 
equivariant (if you rescale the $\pmb X$ matrix the membership probabilities will change).

Comment: How is it related to taking PCA transformation of $J$ most important components?

Comment: Somewhat! (but $J$ is fixed by the data and will be typically larger than the number of most important component)

Comment: thanks a looooot dude! @user603 modifying the code now :D

Comment: @user603 I am still confused some how about the $P$. Do mean $A = x - \mu$ and take the first $J$ colums of $A$? That may perform like choosing $J$ features from the input. And for $D$ you give, is it the diagonal matrix of first $J$ largest eigenvalues?

Comment: I'm not sure what is $A$. If $S_i$ is a covariance matrix, it is square symmetric and can be decomposed as $S_i=\pmb P\pmb D\pmb P'$ where $\pmb D$ is diagonal and $\pmb P$ is orthogonal.

Comment: @user603 Suppose $S_i$ is $p \times p$, then it is the suggested to have $S_i = PDP'$ where $P$ is $p \times k$, assuming $k$ is the dimension to decompose to? Then my $|S_i|$ is still zero as I tried.

Comment: @user603 $\lambda_k$ is the $k-th$ largest eigenvalue I think. Now I use your method to compute $\log |S_i|$ and normal covariance method to get $S_i$ and it works somehow.

Comment: @user603 I chose a 1e-6 threshold

Comment: @user603 Yes, since I found $1e^{-6}$ is already enough somehow. Now what should be be a suggested way of getting a numerically desirable $S_i$? Let $P$ be $p \times k$?

Comment: @user603 I made a mistake now I am considering much smaller threshold like $e^{-30}$, which gives better result.

Comment: yes, then, $\pmb P$ is $p\times k$. But $S_i=\sum_{j=1}^p \log\lambda_i$ so: a) either your eigenvalues are not ordered properly or b) you have many eigenvalues small (but larger than 1e-6). In either case. You can get whatever value you want for $\log|S_i|$, provided it is larger than $\lambda_1$ (the largest eigenvalue) by truncating at the appropriate order $k$