# Using multivariate normal likelihood when determinant of covariance matrix is zero

Tags: maximum-likelihood, matrix, linear-algebra, multivariate-normal-distribution

Estimating a multivariate normal (MVN) model requires minimising the negative log-likelihood of MVN (constant term dropped):

$$
\ell(X|\mu,\Sigma)=\frac{n}{2}\log|\Sigma|+\frac{1}{2}(X-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)
$$

The problem I ran into is the covariance matrix seems to have determinant of zero. I've found a related question which mentioned that a covariance matrix will have zero determinant (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624760/is-the-determinant-of-a-covariance-matrix-always-zero).

So then how are you supposed to use MVN likelihood in estimation? I've found a related question that was answered a long time ago ([Estimating parameters in multivariate classification resulting zero determinant sample covariance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71381/estimating-parameters-in-multivariate-classification-resulting-zero-determinant)) which contained a solution without justification as to *why* the proposed solution works.

[Edit]
A bit of context - I'm using this to train a probabilistic neural network. So MVN log likelihood is my loss function. $N$ in this context is the size of my minibatch and so the covariance matrix is $N \times N$.

Comment: If you know that the covariance matrix has a determinant of zero, you must have found a way to estimate it. ;-) Seriously, not sure what you want to use your estimator for, but the standard ML estimator will result in a likelihood of $\infty$, which is as good as it gets, and it's a legitimate estimator in my view. It will not suit all kinds of uses that somebody has in mind though, and there's a potential issue with uniqueness (haven't thought this through totally) that may or may not bother you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm actually trying to measure uncertainty of my estimator. Suppose $f$ is my model, when I feed in N samples (i.e., $X\in R^{N\times M}, f(X|\theta)=Y$), not only do I want $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ of each individual $y_i$, I also want covariance of every $y$ to every other $y$. So my model actually outputs both $\hat{Y}$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. That's why I thought about approaching this as a MVN likelihood minimisation problem.

Comment: Do you have $N>M$?

Comment: Yea, but the covariance is on $Y\in R^{N\times 1}$.

Comment: What do you want to do, what is your analysis goal? This can be everything from a problem to a nonproblem! If you need $\Sigma^{-1}$, the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse could be the solution. So please tel us your goal!

Comment: @Christian The likelihood will not be infinite when it is properly defined.  Because the MVN is a continuous distribution *on its support,*  almost surely the span of $X$ is exactly correct (assuming it is longer than wide). Restricting all calculations to that subspace reduces the problem to the standard one of estimating the parameters of a nondegenerate MVN distribution. If this argument sounds implausible that is likely because one has in mind the possibility of measurement errors in *all* dimensions. That can be handled by a tiny bit of regularization of the problem.

Comment: @whuber Not sure I'd call the likelihood "properly defined" in this way if in fact the support of the underlying distribution has full dimensionality, only the available observations are on a lower dimensional subspace, which in reality can easily happen. Of course the approach that you propose can technically be used also in that situation.

Comment: @Christian The important point is that because $N\ge M,$ the chance is zero that the space spanned by the data does not equal the true support. Thus, my approach is not just a "technical" subterfuge: it is the correct likelihood according to standard formulations.

Comment: @whuber Well, we use continuous models, but real data is discrete. In reality the chance is not zero for sure. Have a look at Iris data, lots of points on the same lower-d hyperplane, still everybody uses continuous models for them.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I'm actually using this to train a probabilistic neural network. So MVN log likelihood is my loss function. $N$ in this context is the size of my minibatch and so the covariance matrix is $N \times N$. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @Christian That is why I mentioned regularization as a possible solution.  But purely as a logical matter, appealing to the deviations between "real life data" and models amounts to abandoning a useful approach for analyzing the data and so can scarcely be conceived of as a constructive way to address the present situation.

Comment: Please add this context (as an edit) to the question, it is important. All extra information given in comments should be in the Q itself!

Comment: The reason your determinant is zero is because you have perfect colinearity between the variables. One or more of your variables can be expressed as a linear function of the rest.